# Wait for a Javascript function to finish executing and fetch the response from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I've a array of images and I am uploading these images to firebase storage.

```
      data = {
        ...data,
        downloadedUrl: [],
      };
    
      if (data?.image?.length) {
        for (const image of data?.image) {
          await uploadFile(image, data);
        }
      }
```

`uploadFile` handles the logic for uploading the image to firebase.

```
  const uploadFile = useCallback((file, data) => {
    if (!file) return;

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/images/${file.name}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snap_shot) => {},
      (err) => console.log(err),
      async () => {
        await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
          data.downloadedUrl.push(url);
        });
      }
    );
  }, []);
```

It takes few seconds to get the `downloadedUrl` from `uploadTask` and I want to store this `downloadedUrl` in firebase `firestore` when I get all the urls. 
 
Issue with the current approach is that before getting the urls, the other function start executing and I am not able to upload this data on firestore with the `downloadedUrl`
Here's the full function when someone clicks on form `submit`

```
const handleFormSubmit = useCallback(
    async (data) => {
      setLoading(true);
      data = {
        ...data,
        downloadedUrl: [],
      };

      if (data?.image?.length) {
        for (const image of data?.image) {
          await uploadFile(image, data);
        }
      }

      if (data.downloadedUrl.length) {
        uploadDataToFirestore(data);
      }
 
      if (!data.downloadedUrl?.length) {
        dispatch(handleAlertState({ message: "Error Occured!!!" }));
        router.push("/services");
        return;
      }
      setLoading(false);
      router.push("/");
    },
    [dispatch, router, uploadDataToFirestore, uploadFile]
  );

  const uploadDataToFirestore = useCallback(
    async (data) => {

      await setDoc(doc(db, "form-responses"), data)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("response", response);
          dispatch(
            handleAlertState({
              message: "Success. Your request has been sent. Thank You.",
            })
          );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error", error);
        });
    },
    [dispatch]
  );
```

This bellow block of code executes the code while images are being uploaded to the cloud storage.
I want to wait for the downloadedUrl and then upload the urls to firebase firestore.

```
      if (!data.downloadedUrl?.length) {
        dispatch(handleAlertState({ message: "Error Occured!!!" }));
        router.push("/services");
        return;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create array of promises
2. Use **Promise.all** to watch for every promise

```js
const uploadFile = useCallback((file, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!file) reject();

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/images/${file.name}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

    uploadTask.on(
      'state_changed',
      snap_shot => {},
      err => reject(err),
      () => resolve(getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)),
    );

  });
}, []);

let allPromises = [];
if (data?.image?.length) {
  for (const image of data?.image) {
    allPromises.push(uploadFile(image, data));
  }
}

let uploadedUrls = await Promise.all(allPromises);
console.log(uploadedUrls);
```

`await Promise.all` take an array of promises, we created a new array which holds the promise returned from `uploadFile` function. when all promises resolved then promise.all resolved as well and return array of urls. we `await` for Promise.all so it will not execute next line until resolved

Comment: why do `async () => { getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(url => { resolve(url); }); }` when you can do `() => resolve(getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref))` - the latter being better code, AND it'll properly handle rejections from `getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)`

Comment: @Bravo could you suggest an edit?

Comment: no @random_18 - I've shown exactly what to change - I'm only 99% sure I'm right, but my suggestion would handle errors (rejections) whereas the code I referenced in this answer would not :p

Comment: @random_18 seems it was edited with ALMOST my suggestion - there is absolutely NO need for that callback to be async now - since the code does not need to `await` anything (note: the original code didn't need async/await for that code either

Comment: Now that little block looks better (I haven't checked ALL the code though) - nothing against the creator if this answer, but `async`/`await` seems to be overused these days

Comment: Muhammad could you please explain the code, how it works synchronously. I am able to achieve the functionality I mentioned and its executing like I wanted

Comment: `await Promise.all` take an array of promises, we created a new array which holds the promise returned from `uploadFile` function.
when all promises resolved then promise.all resolved as well and return array of urls.
we `await` for Promise.all so it will not execute next line until resolved